# Do xunit tests run in total isolation?

Tags: c#, xunit.net

If I have a static class:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static string Bar = "baz";
}
```

And inside a xunit test I do something like this (contrived):

```
public class FooTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Bar_can_be_set_to_buz()
    {
        Foo.Bar = "buz";
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Some_other_test()
    {
        //Is Foo.Bar "buz", or is there isolation ?
    }
}
```

Is the external static class shared by both tests, or is there complete isolation between tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each test gets a new instance of the test class. Any static state will shared amongst all tests.